# Buildroot toolchain with openssl

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, buildroot, gnu-toolchain, linux-toolchain

I am using Buildroot (2017.02.5) to build a custom cross compilation toolchain. I have two buildroot configurations; one to build the RFS and one purely to build a toolchain. I have things configured this way because I don't want the toolchain to be rebuilt unless I intentionally rebuild it- the configuration which builds the RFS references this toolchain as an external toolchain.

Generally, the built toolchain works fine, but I have some existing applications (Linux userspace) which `#include`'s `<openssl/md5.h>`. When I try to compile this, I get a `"<openssl/md5.h>: No such file or directory"` error, which is expected because the sysroot dir of the generated toolchain does not contain an openssl directory.

How can I make buildroot include openssl in the toolchain? All searches I have done seem to point to cross compiling openssl for my embedded target, which is not an issue. The issue is that I need to include it in the toolchain.

I have Target packages --> Libraries --> Crypto --> openssl set to y, but I don't think this makes any difference in this scenario since I believe it relates only to the RFS (and the defconfig in question does not build an RFS, only a toolchain).

I could compile OpenSSL outside of the buildroot tree and install it to the sysroot dir, but this doesn't seem correct as it would pollute sysroot.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here- any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's there. You need to create a packages in terms of Buildroot for your custom software.

Answer (score 1):

After some further reading of the buildroot documentation (which is very good), I figured that packages selected under `Target packages` do in fact get pushed into the `sysroot` of the toolchain (or are supposed to at least) which would make sense. The reason this didn't appear to be working was because I was doing a `make toolchain` as opposed to `make all` (or just a simple `make`). The packages didn't get built with the former, so they weren't in the `sysroot` of the toolchain.

Comment: In Buildroot 2017.08, you will also be able to do 'make sdk' to build all the packages and also make the result relocatable. However, you have to make sure yourself that the openssl that ends up in your rootfs is exactly the same as the one in your SDK.